# I don't understand the execution flow of redux thunks with chaining

Tags: redux, react-redux, easy-peasy

This is an example code from the easy peasy docs but the same question goes for createThunk from redux-toolkit:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const saveTodo = useStoreActions(actions => actions.todos.saveTodo);
  const onSaveClick = useCallback(
    // We chain on the promise returned by dispatching the thunk
    //                                  
    () => saveTodo('Learn easy peasy').then(() => {
      // redirect on success
      history.push('/done');
    }),
    [saveTodo]
  );
}
```

1. Lets say saveTodo saves a todo in store(changing the store). changing the store triggers a re-render of subscribed components. So, how does the "then" logic execute anyway?
2. Lets say that saving the todo will not re-render the component immediately but after executing the logic in "then". What if I want to display a loading spinner while saving the todo and just then execute the "history.push..."?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence would be:

1. Component calls `saveTodo()`
2. The `saveTodo` function I assume is one that already wraps the actual call to `dispatch`, so internally that runs `dispatch(actualSaveTodoThunkActionCreator())`.  This creates [a new "thunk function"](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#writing-thunks) and passes it to `dispatch`.
3. The thunk middleware sees that the "action" is actually a thunk function, stops it from continuing onwards, and calls it: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#how-does-the-middleware-work
4. The body of the thunk runs, and returns a Promise
5. The thunk middleware returns that Promise.
6. The returned Promise is passed back through any other middleware, and finally returned from the original `dispatch()` call
7. The code in `useCallback()` gets the Promise, and chains a `.then()` call on it
8. Normal Promise resolution happens at some point in the future.
9. The Promise internally invokes the `.then()` callback after it has been resolved.

Per the second question, you could set loading state in the component before and after the dispatch:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components

Comment: Thank you but you missed my point. When the component rerenders(after updating the store) the previous onSaveClick is destroyed but a promise is returned to it. can you understand the conflict?

Comment: Ah... sorry, no, I'm afraid I'm really not sure what you're asking here, then. Can you clarify?

Comment: Within all the steps you mentioned where the component re-rendering takes place? before the promise gets resolved or after or in between ? thanks.

Comment: Mmm... depends on where in that sequence you're dispatching the action after the request is done.